# Wordpress - Check if post has update

Tags: php, wordpress, last-modified

How can I check whether a post has been updated or not in Wordpress?

```
if (post_has_edit())
    the_modified_time();
else
    the_time();
```

Is there a function like `post_has_edit()`?

Comment: `if (last edit date <> creation date)`, probably

Comment: Is it a function o_O ?

Comment: Can you say what do you mean ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From the Wordpress docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_time):

> If the post or page is not yet modified, the modified time is the same as the creation time.

So you can just use `the_modified_time()`, and if the post hasn't been modified, it will return the creation time instead.

To check whether the post has been modified, check whether `the_modified_time() == the_time()`.

Comment: `the_modified_time() == the_time()` Should be `get_the_time() == get_the_modified_time()`.

Comment: If the post was published as a draft, `get_the_time()` Will be the current time while `get_the_modified_time()` will be the time the post was first made into a draft.

Answer (score 0):

If you need check `date` for **multiple post** on **same page** (for example: archive page, search page or any `WP_Query`), you can use

```
if(get_the_modified_date == get_the_date) :

    // Do stuff here

endif;
```

And remember use `!=` for is not equal :)